# Is it possible to feed data chunks to a 32-bit app to avoid risking out of memory exceptions?

Tags: xna, out-of-memory, shared-memory

I'm making an XNA game and its main idea is to be able to use lots of game objects at once which means lots of respective textures and sounds effects. When a map is big enough (and they usually are) the game might create too many objects and it causes out of memory exception.

Loading map chunks is part of the solution, as the player usually moves slow enough for the game to load the next chunk, but sound effects are a problem — when too many game events call their sounds, there is a noticeable lag when loading a new sound in usual fashion.

I wonder if there is a way to load resources by swapping memory chunks between the actual game and a background loading helper application back or something like that to increase loading speed.

---

I'm thinking of using virtual Ram drives to store temp data, it might be fast enough.

Comment: Loading chunks async would solve sound glitches, wouldn't it?

Comment: That made me think about disks fast enough to read from almost instantly, I think RAM drive with "raw" data (as close as it can get to simply read and use without conversion) could be a solution.